# How to write a list into column of another csv file using python

Tags: python, list, csv, file, row

I have one csv file(name.csv) which contains the names a list of email address. I am trying to write one csv file with name as it's first column and email as it's second column. But in my final.csv the names are written properly but the emails are written one in a cell. Here is my code snippet.

```
data = [['Email'], ['connect@viu.ca', 'worldviu@viu.ca', 'registration@viu.ca', 'study@viu.ca', 'advising@viu.ca', 'advising.international@viu.ca', 'info@viu.ca'  ], ['[]']]
with  open('name.csv') as robj1, open('final.csv', 'w', newline='')  as wobj:
    csv_read = reader(robj1)
    csv_writer = writer(wobj)
    for row in csv_read:
        row.append(data[i])
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
        i+=1
```

and the output i am getting is

[image: the output of my final.csv]

and my desired output is
[[image: desired output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what your desired output CSV file would be for that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data list is a double list. Change it to a single list like this

```
data = [['Email'], ['connect@viu.ca', 'worldviu@viu.ca', 'registration@viu.ca', 'study@viu.ca', 'advising@viu.ca', 'advising.international@viu.ca', 'info@viu.ca'  ], ['[]']]
```

Final.csv will be something like this
[image]

**EDIT:** To get rid of the other bracket

`row.append(", ".join(data[i]))`

Output will look like this.
[image]

Comment: I tried it but i am still getting the same output

Comment: You mean you didn't get the output I have attached?

Comment: If you are looking for just the email id's without any brackets, replace this line of the code also ...see edited answer